# Is there some comprehensive, overall classification of puzzles?

Tags: puzzle-theory

Currently, I've begun to study puzzles and wonder if some book exists or something which breaks down all puzzles to types and describes them.
I'm not a native English speaker, so I might be confused with term "puzzle".
Maybe it's more properly to say not "classification of puzzles", but "classification of *logic* puzzles".
If there isn't, can you please suggest the most notable (in your opinion) book on (logic) puzzle theory.

Comment: maybe this should be in meta?

Comment: Interesting question. I would think that very well made puzzles may be too original to categorize, a puzzle that revolves around its own concepts, its own flavor of logical reasoning, like the pirates and gold coins puzzle. For the most part, lots of logic puzzles CAN be categorized easily, ex. Puzzles where a group follows a plan to achieve something, like the two levers puzzle, the chessboard and coins, or the flippin circular prison of unknown size (which I still can't understand the solution to ._.).

Comment: Just look at our tags!

Comment: maybe u mean something like http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/Game_Theory/Contents.html
but it's a lot.

Comment: @Jan Ivan not sure about it yet, but looks promising. Will think about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot think of any books however, wikipedia has a quite detailed list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puzzle#Types).

The website contains a list of links to different puzzle 'genres', and the pages linked to also contain more lists. This is a very broad topic, and some of the puzzles linked to will absolutely use logic. I think what you are looking for is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Logic_puzzles), it contains information on logic puzzles specifically.

I have copied the page so everything is on-site:

[image]

Comment: And what makes this classification better than other possibilities? The classification system of Wikipedia articles isn't exactly known for its perfection

Comment: @randal'thor this is the only list I know of, so I have shared it. It's not necessarily the best, and it's certainly not perfection, but I think it's pretty good.

Comment: Adding to Rand's comment, Rubik's Cube is listed twice

Comment: I don't see a problem with listing any one puzzle twice as an example if it falls under two different categories.

Comment: Agreed with everybody.
Compilation of wikipedia's list + Puzzling tags list + [this list](http://wiki.logic-masters.de/index.php?title=Kategorie:Maintype/en) is not an ideal solution, but it's still very good solution :) Thanks!